# Sanitize user submitted HTML but keep safe embedded iframes

Tags: java, javascript, html, security, ckeditor

I need to sanitize user inputs  of malicious html & submitted by `CKEditor`. I currently use `owasp-java-html-sanitizer`. for this purpose but it removes embedded iframes as well. But I have genuine use cases like embedding a YouTube video or slide share presentation within posts.

How could I allow such embedded iframes safely? I use Java.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to allow the iframe element and source attribute to your Html policy.
You can do it like the following example modified from the [java doc](https://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distrib/javadoc/org/owasp/html/HtmlPolicyBuilder.html)

```
 // Define the policy.
 Function<HtmlStreamEventReceiver, HtmlSanitizer.Policy> policy
     = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
         .allowElements("a", "p", "iframe")
         .allowAttributes("href").onElements("a")
         .allowAttributes("source").onElements("iframe")
         .toFactory();

 // Sanitize your output.
 HtmlSanitizer.sanitize(myHtml, policy.apply(myHtmlStreamRenderer));
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! but the input html is like : *`<div class="embeddedContent" data-resizetype="noresize" data-align="none" data-oembed="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fC5N2EPCesk"><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fC5N2EPCesk?wmode=transparent&amp;jqoemcache=paWu1" width="425" height="349" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>`* & in the sanitized output I get all the attributes stripped out. How do I prevent the attributes from being stripped out? Btw Is it safe to allow iframes as such with all these attributes ?

Comment: The sanitized output I get for above input is : *`<div><iframe></iframe></div>`* which is of no use.. Thanks!

Comment: @user01, this seems pretty straightforward.  Just add any attributes you'd like to keep to the `.allowAttributes(...).onElements("iframe")` call.  For example, `.allowAttributes("src", "wmode", "jqoemcache", "width", "height","allowfullscreen", "allowscriptaccess", "scrolling","frameborder").onElements("iframe")`.  (Note that it's "src", not "source".)  

Having said that, it's probably not safe to allow your iframes to do all these things...