# Sanitize html keeping embedded youtube etc videos/other media

Tags: java, security, ckeditor, sanitization, html-sanitizing

I currently use owasp-java-html-sanitizer to sanitize user inputs from **[CKEditor/ FCKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)** but it removes embedded iframes as well. But I have genuine use cases like embedding a YouTube video or slide share presentation within posts.

How do I allow such embedded iframes safely?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sanitize user submitted HTML but keep safe embedded iframes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341980/sanitize-user-submitted-html-but-keep-safe-embedded-iframes)

Comment: Please do not duplicate your posts.